# Oracle table of Objects in memory

Tags: oracle, object

I've got the following type:

```
 create or replace type autocontrole2.DifferentStatesSAC as object (
  AUTOCONTROLE_STATUS_CODE_ID NUMBER(2),
  DATUM_BEGIN DATE,
  DATUM_EIND DATE)
```

With the following SQL, the error is "ORA 06531 - reference to uninitialized collection"

```
declare
    type TableDifferentStatesSAC is table of autocontrole2.DifferentStatesSAC;
    StatutenSAC TableDifferentStatesSAC;
begin
    StatutenSAC(1).AUTOCONTROLE_STATUS_CODE_ID := 6;
    StatutenSAC(1).DATUM_BEGIN := sysdate;
    StatutenSAC(1).DATUM_EIND := sysdate;
end;
```

With the following SQL, the error is "wrong number of types or arguments in call to DifferentStatesSAC()":

```
declare
    type TableDifferentStatesSAC is table of autocontrole2.DifferentStatesSAC;
    StatutenSAC TableDifferentStatesSAC := autocontrole2.DifferentStatesSAC;
begin
    StatutenSAC(1).AUTOCONTROLE_STATUS_CODE_ID := 6;
    StatutenSAC(1).DATUM_BEGIN := sysdate;
    StatutenSAC(1).DATUM_EIND := sysdate;
end;
```

I want to create a 'table' in memory that contains an object with 3 values.

any ideas how I can add objects to this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the nested table:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE TableDifferentStatesSAC IS TABLE OF DifferentStatesSAC;
  3     StatutenSAC TableDifferentStatesSAC;
  4  BEGIN
  5     /* calling the constructor */
  6     StatutenSAC := TableDifferentStatesSAC();
  7     /* adding room for elements */
  8     StatutenSAC.extend();
  9     /* filling first element */
 10     StatutenSAC(1) := DifferentStatesSAC(6, SYSDATE, SYSDATE);
 11  END;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

You can also fill the table with a single command:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE TableDifferentStatesSAC IS TABLE OF DifferentStatesSAC;
  3     StatutenSAC TableDifferentStatesSAC;
  4  BEGIN
  5     /* calling the constructor */
  6     StatutenSAC := TableDifferentStatesSAC(
  7                       DifferentStatesSAC(6, SYSDATE, SYSDATE)
  8                    );
  9  END;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Find out more in the [online documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#i20383).